# Targetting divs that are inside other divs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this hover to work. **The goal is when someone hovers over div.lol the div.sdf hides.**

Not sure how to add the div.dang into the script to make this work. If I delete the div.dang my script works.

```
<div class="ugh"><div class="lol">test</div></div>
<div class="dang"><div class="sdf">sdf</div></div>


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lol').hover(function(){
        $('.ugh').nextAll('.sdf:first').hide();
    },function(){
        $('.ugh').nextAll('.sdf:first').show();
    })
});
```

Here is a link to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/297/

Comment: There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/302/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
  $('.lol').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().find('.sdf').hide();
  },function(){
    $(this).parent().next().find('.sdf').show();
  });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/csbVW/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lol').hover(function () {
        $(this).parent().next('.dang').find('.sdf').hide();
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().next('.dang').find('.sdf').show();
    })
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nLybj/301/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide/show all elements with class "sdf",then you can try this:

```
$('.lol').hover(
   function(){
        $('.sdf').hide();
    },function(){
        $('.sdf').show();
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/306/)

to select next closest:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lol').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().find('.sdf:first').hide();
    },function(){
        $(this).parent().next().find('.sdf:first').show();
    }) 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/316/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I just want the next closest, not all.